# Ubuntu 20 cannot pull mongo image

Tags: docker

I'm using docker on ubuntu 20 my docker-compose file consists of nginx, nodejs, redis, mongo images. When I do `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml -c docker-compose.prod.yml <stack_name>` it pulls only nginx, nodejs, redis but not mongodb and `docker image ls` does not have mongo image.

When I do `docker pull mongo:latest` its stucked forever at

[image]

Comment: I just tried pulling it and it worked for me. It might be network issues on your end or a full hard-drive?

Comment: I try restarting ubuntu and it solved